# Accessing the n row from the right or left of the x row

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to select the data from the left of a row.
Lets assume this table:

```
create table user (
   ID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
);
```

The rows of this table look like that:

```
ID 
1
3
4
7
8
15
18
19
```

What I want to do, is to select data from the row which has ID = 15, to the 4th row from left of it, which has ID 3, how can I do that, without using BETWEEN in query.

Comment: Does your data contains one column really? or this is simplified model?

Comment: It contains way more columns, this one is a simplified version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I want to do, is to select data from the row which has ID = 15, to the 4th row from left of it:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE id < 15
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 4
```

If you need the 4th row **only** then use above query as a subquery, and in outer query use backward sorting + `LIMIT 1`.

---

If MySQL version is 8+ then use ROW_NUMBER() in CTE.

Comment: `id <= 15` and `LIMIT 5` ?

Comment: @Zakaria Imagine that the value 15 is taken from somewhere else, and the row with `id=15` not exists in the table... in your case the output will be wrong.

Comment: @marc_s While editing, please watch what you are editing. If a quote from a question is inserted in the answer, do not convert it into the text of the answer.